# ic_launcher showing default android icon instead of mine in android

Tags: android

ic_launcher showing default android icon instead of mine custom app icon, I don't understand what is wrong, anybody know this issue......

I rename my custom logo to "ic_launcher"

I have switch my project from windows to mac android studio and I config my manifest my as

```
<application
        android:name="com.XXX.XXXX"
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
        android:theme="@style/NewActivityTheme" >  


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
}
```

defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

Comment: check do you have a mipmap resource directory. If you have one, you have to replace the icon there. Instead of `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` try `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

Comment: Try clean and re build your project, this might work

Comment: copy again clean and rebuild your project try it..

Answer (score 0):

Do you put your custom icon "ic_launcher.png" to each 5 drawable folders?